# complex entity type with an unknown number of columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure that I need to call. The stored procedure has a dynamic query that is stored in a @query variable and executed like so execute(@query). The reason for this is because a portion of the columns are dynamic based on the passed parameters. From reading up on calling stored procedures in entity framework you create an object with properties that are the same as the column names. The obvious problem here is that a portion of the columns will be unknown until the stored procedure gets called so I can't simply define them as properties in the object.
How can I handle this situation?
Is there a way to do this without using properties. All I want is a DataTable returned that I can bind to my DataGrid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to bypass entity framework, and just use a ADO.NET SqlCommand.
If it's a dynamic query, it's probably not something you'd want to treat as an "entity" anyway.

Comment: Right. That makes sense. I though since I'm using entity framework I SHOULD go through it somehow for every case. Thanks.